# Magento 1.9.1.1 changes or release notes

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.1

I am unable to find the list of changes in the release notes. Are there major changes to this release. Can anyone list the changes?

Answer (score 1):

CE 1.9.1.1 Release Notes are here: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.1.1.html

Starting with CE 1.9.1 and EE 1.14.1, Release Notes are in the User Guides.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the release notes for magento community 1.9.1.0

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html

There isn't a CE Version 1.9.1.1 yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the CE version 1.9.1.1 is available for download. https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

Comment: This is because there was a security update. There is no other changelog I guess.